# Google Cloud Tasks Retries is over the Max retries setting?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-tasks

How come is it possible for a task to be retried more times than the limit?
As seen here

[Retries > Max Retries?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW9Rv.png)

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxtZB.png)